# IOS switch control scrolling in openGL backed UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, accessibility, objective-c++

I have a OpenGl backed UiView that implements a scrollable list with multiple items inside. I have created an accessibility tree with information about the element inside UIView and attached it to its accessibilityElements. Everything works fine except When I turn on switch control, It does not provide scroll action when the item inside is focused. It only shows tap action.

My question is how I can turn on the scroll action, and how ios determines what switch actions are available. I have tried several accessibility api includes providing accessibilityScroll, but none of them seems to enable scroll action in switch control.

Thanks in advance